# Definition of Function Pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers

i am working with an sdk, where i have to define a call-back function, the problem is, that the "sample" code are shipped with global functions and a very procedural approach. To bring it into a structure, i was creating classes. But i couldn't get the argument syntax right, when defining and declaring it O_o

So here is my working example:

**In my code.h:**

```
void   (*MessageHandler)(int msgType, char* msg){printf("\n%s\n", msg);}
```

this works fine, when i call in my code.cpp

```
void (*opFunc)(int msgType, char* msg) =  MessageHandler;
```

But i want to do the definition in my cpp, and i couldn't find the syntax, normally it should be:

```
void (*Code::MessageHandler)(int msgType, char* msg){
    printf("\n%s\n", msg);
}
```

But this doesn't work and i couldn't find any hint how to fix it. Would be nice to get a hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a function, define it as you would do with any function:

```
void Code::MessageHandler(int msgType, char* msg){
    printf("\n%s\n", msg);
}
```

Its name, `Code::MessageHandler` is actually a function pointer of the right type. This works as expected if `Code` is a `namespace`, if it is a `class`, you'll have to declare it `static` to get an unbound reference.

Also, consider using `typedef` to make the source code more readable.

Comment: No, unless you use method-pointers, which are tricky. The usual approach is passing `this` to the static method as a parameter: although it is static, it can access private members of the class.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to define a function for a function pointer within your `Code` class? You can just create a function (either static member or global function) and use the name of that function as a pointer.

```
void Code::MessageHandler( int msgType, char* msg ){
  printf( "\n%s\n", msg );
}

// Create a function pointer called fn to point at a static function
void (*fn)( int, char * ) = &Code::MessageHandler;
```

Note again, that this won't work if MessageHandler is not a static function, otherwise you'd be dealing with member function pointers, which are very different from function pointers.

If you wanted `Code::MessageHandler` to itself be a function pointer, then you'd assign it to a global function upon construction.

Comment: Code:: is my class and i want to modify member-variables within the MessageHandler function, is there a clever way without doing the function static?

Comment: Sure, you can have the first parameter be a pointer to a `Code` class, and access members in this way.

Comment: `Code` is a class type, and not an actual object. You can pass in a pointer to an instance of a `Code` class.

Comment: ...sure, i was confused a bit, totally forgot to create an Object O_o